# Why did this character get trapped as well?

Tags: plot-explanation, goosebumps

In Goosebumps (2015) movie, we can see that

> R.L. Stine writes another story that all the monsters he released will get trapped in a book, which he presumed to happen as all things happen when written with the typewriter. But when the book started to absorb all the monsters he created, it started to pull Hannah too. I understand that Hannah is also created by R.L. Stine and not naturally human.

But why did he mention in his book that Hannah will get trapped too? Can't he just mention the other monsters without Hannah and complete the book?

Answer (score 1):

Because then he couldn't bring her back in the epilogue, the quintessential plot twist that R.L. Stine books are known for. Of course he ***could have*** written the book in a very detailed way, but then the plot of the story would be different. Of course, **Zach** only wrote the ending, as R.L. told him to, so he missed the subtle details that a writer would have.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense na... Trapping a character just for setting them free. Stine could have written the same story with just Hannah's name deleted

Comment: They were in a rush...

Comment: Yeah that maybe the case.. or maybe they just made a mistake because u don't mention someone getting trapped in a book without actually meaning it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the super creepy twist ending of the whole thing! Think about it. Hannah. The Hannah that Zack knew was sucked into the book and trapped with the monsters forever. Stine never opened the book again so she is still in there. The Hannah at the end was from a new book "I may have written one more book" - Stine. So that was a new Hannah written with the same experiences and memories. Essentially, Zack and Stine were now living with the new copy of Hannah, while the real Hannah is still trapped forever with the monsters! Awesome creepy and messed up twist ending!